#1265 - Data truncated for column
I have a table with a b_mag field that contains about 13000 records which is VARCHAR but I need FLOAT because I have to sort them numerically and do other things.
The values that b_mag contains are all of the type 12.45, 9.5, 10.5 and some empty fields.
I created a new b_mag_num field of type FLOAT and ran this query:
UPDATE `vega_ngc_ic_messier_catalog` SET `b_mag_num` = `b_mag` WHERE `ID`=`ID`

but I get this error:
#1265 - Data truncated for column 'b_mag_num' at row 8

I don't understand why the data is truncated, FLOAT can contain the type of data that is passed to it.
Thanks to anyone who can help me.

see the create table which size b_mag_num has and check b_mag if is "bigger" like bifint or so

Do you have any rows where b_mag is an empty string or contains non-numeric data?

In b-mag there are empty fields and numeric fields. There are no non-numeric fields.

To avoid truncations, it is probably better to update with a cast so to specify the decimal value precision.
UPDATE `vega_ngc_ic_messier_catalog` SET `b_mag_num` = CAST(`b_mag` AS DECIMAL(10,6)) WHERE COALESCE(`b_mag`, 0)<>0

Alternatively, you could also alter the column type.

Thanks, your query correctly populated the b_mag_num column for me!
